# How can we collaborate a multiple Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, merge

How can we collect multiple excel data sheets into one?
Is there any tool available for this purpose?
I want it to collect all excel sheets and be merged together whenever necessary.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide more details and coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenXML SDK for this purpose, check out the detailed explanation here:

[Merging Simple Content from Excel 2007 Workbooks and Worksheets by Using the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee396252(v=office.12).aspx)